# How to call a class function which only argument is &

Tags: c++11

Here's my code:

```
class Patient {
 public:
  const int patientId;
  const PatientKind kind;
  const bool hasInsurance;
  std::vector<ProcedureKind> procedures;
  Patient(int, PatientKind, bool);
  bool addProcedure(const ProcedureKind procedure);
  double billing();
  virtual double liability() = 0;
};
class Hospital {
 public:
  Patient &addPatient(const PatientInfo &);
};`
```

I don't know how to write:

```
Patient &Hospital::addPatient(const PatientInfo &)
{

}
```

Whatever I try to return or pass as argument gives me an error... Also, I don't understand what is this function expecting as an argument with just &?
Any kind of help / insight will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to implement a header definition someone else wrote. That `&` means that the function expects a reference to an instance of `PatientInfo`. In the implementation, the only thing you have to do is to give the parameter a name like so:

```
Patient& addPatient(const PatientInfo& info)
{
     // do whatever you need with 'info'
}
```

You can read more about c++ function declaration and implementation in any basic c++ text.

Comment: So, it is not O.K. to just have 
public:
  Patient &addPatient(const PatientInfo &);
But I need to add variable name after & like : (const PatientInfo & x). 
Or it can stay like that, but I just need to pass a Patientinfo type to it?
Another problem is, I don't know what to return. the hospital class only has this:
class Hospital {
 public:
  Patient &addPatient(const PatientInfo &);
};`
But the function is of type hospital... So I have no idea how to use this. And yes, you are right, this is existing project I want to test.

Comment: It's ok to have a nameless parameter in the header definition, but you need to give the parameter a name in the .cpp implementation. the return type is a reference to an instance of `Patient`. So you probably have to add a member variable of that type to your `Hospital` class and return a reference to that. Again, this is very basic c++ stuff. Please take a little time to familiarize yourself with the language basics first.

Comment: I can't add a member variable of Patient type. I am getting object of abstract class type "Patient" is not allowed: -- function "Patient::liability" is a pure virtual function.

Comment: I assume you are supposed to search for an existing patient that matches the info. That is your problem :-) When you find it, it exists in the data structure and you can return a reference to it. But what if you don't find one? Is there an instance of Patient called the nullpatient or similar? If not, you have a problem, as your function MUST return something. perhaps you are supposed to raise an exception?